# Underline text in HTML

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, html-table, internet-explorer-6

I want to write the simpliest example of the following image

[image]

My example should work in ie6,7,8,9 and so on. So I can't use float or anything helpfull. I made [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyso750m/2/) using table

```
<table width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td width="45px"><span>e-mail</span>
        </td>
        <td align="center"> <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">test@gmail.com</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="45px"></td>
        <td align="center"> <span>(email)</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

, but the bottom (email) have margin from the line.
[image]

And I want that everything was like on my first image. Thanks

Comment: Check `vertical-align` property

Comment: This is not about underlining text, this is about drawing a horizontal line between pieces of text. It is unclear why you say that you “can’t use float or anything helpful”, since IE supports floats, though you don’t say why floats would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this.
Check this [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nyso750m/37/)

```
<table width="500px" style="padding:0px; border-spacing:1px">
<tr>
    <td width="45px" style="padding:0px"><span>e-mail</span>

    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px"> test@gmail.com <hr noshade style="border-top:1px; -webkit-margin-before: 0; -webkit-margin-after: 0; -webkit-margin-top: 0; -webkit-margin-bottom: 0;"/> </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="45px" style="padding:0px"></td>
    <td align = "center" style = "margin-top:0px; padding:0px">(email)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The “margin” you are referring to is partly spacing between cells, partly padding inside the cell, partly leading, and partly spacing in the font. In your approach, the simplest fix is probably to set cell spacing to zero and to move the cell content upwards a bit, using relative positioning.

```html
<table width="500" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="45">e-mail
        </td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 1px solid">test@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="45"></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="position: relative; top: -0.15em">(email)</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

- apply `border-spacing: 0` to the table's style (`border-collapse: collapse`would work too, aswell as `cellspacing` attribute)
- add `padding: 0` to the `td`containing `<span>(email)</span>`

To increase the space between the upper e-mail-adress and the bottom border (which you did not mention explicitly but is not the same as your example image):

- move the `border-bottom` style from `div` to its parent `td`
- add a `padding-bottom` to the same `td`